# How to get my Bootstrap card to scale only down?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a game I am making with html, JS. Currently, how it works is you get a resource, once you get enough of that resource you unlock a new "helper" and it appears in the helper div. Everything works greatly and properly but when it gets add to the list, you will see in the pictures that the cards are not aligned anymore because the bootstrap card scales up and down, rather than just down. How do I keep my cards at the same x axis?

The first picture is before and the second is after. You will see the cards are not perfectly aligned on top anymore

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.buy-wisp-container {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top:10px
}

#buy-conjurer-container{

  display: none;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top:10px

}

#buy-excavator-container{

  display: none;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top:10px

}

#buy-sciencewisp-container{

  display: none;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top:10px

}

.left-side-div {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

.right-side-div {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}


.container{

  height: 80vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display:flex;

}


#helpers-card{


  display:inline-block;
  min-height:138px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="card text-center bg-dark text-light" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title" id="item-name">Mana (<span id="total-mana-display" class="text-light-blue">0</span>)<span id="mana-increment-display"class="text-green" style="position: absolute; font-size: 1rem; display:none">+<span id="mana-increment-amount">1</span></span></h3>
          <p class="card-text" id="attributes-text">
  
          </p>
          <hr>
          <p class="card-text" id="req-text">
  
          </p>

          <button class="btn collect-btn" onclick="collectMana(player.mana.collectPower)">Collect</button>

        </div>

        
    </div>

    <div class="card text-center bg-dark text-light " id="helpers-card" style="width: 18rem;">
      
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title" id="item-name">Helpers</h3>
          <p class="card-text" id="attributes-text">
  
          </p>
          <hr>

          <div class="helper-container">

            <div class="buy-wisp-container" style="">
                <div class="left-side-div">
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-500" id="req-text">
                        Wisp (<span id="wisp-amount">0</span>)
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="right-side-div" style="margin:0;float:right;width:50%">
                    
                    <button class="btn purchase-helper-btn font-weight-500" onclick="recruitHelper('wisp', 1)">Recruit (<span id="wisp-cost">5</span> mana)</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="buy-conjurer-container">
                <div class="left-side-div">
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-500" id="req-text">
                        Conjurer (<span id="conjurer-amount">0</span>)
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="right-side-div" style="margin:0;float:right;width:50%">
                    
                    <button class="btn purchase-helper-btn font-weight-500" onclick="recruitHelper('conjurer', 1)">Recruit (<span id="conjurer-cost">15</span> mana)</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="buy-excavator-container" style="">
                <div class="left-side-div">
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-500" id="req-text">
                        Excavator (<span id="excavator-amount">0</span>)
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="right-side-div" style="margin:0;float:right;width:50%">
                    
                    <button class="btn purchase-helper-btn font-weight-500" onclick="recruitHelper('excavator', 1)">Recruit (<span id="excavator-cost">10</span> mana)</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="buy-sciencewisp-container" style="">
                <div class="left-side-div">
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-500" id="req-text">
                        Science Wisp (<span id="excavator-amount">0</span>)
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="right-side-div" style="margin:0;float:right;width:50%">
                    
                    <button class="btn purchase-helper-btn font-weight-500" onclick="recruitHelper('sciencewisp', 1)">Recruit (<span id="sciencewisp-cost">10</span> mana)</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            

          </div> 
          
        </div>
        
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76923730/edit) and add some code to your question.

Comment: Um... I believe you put the CSS in the box labeled "HTML" and you forgot to include any HTML. Please make a functioning code snippet to we can see the issue you are having with the code

Answer (score 1):

change `align-items: center;` to `align-items: flex-start;` in `.container`

I think this code should work

Answer (score 1):

Put those cards in a container with a class `d-flex`. In `flex` display both cards will expand equally on vertical directly and will also remain in the center.

```css
.buy-wisp-container {
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top:10px
}

#buy-conjurer-container{
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top:10px

}

#buy-excavator-container{
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top:10px
}

#buy-sciencewisp-container{
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top:10px
}

.left-side-div {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: left;
}

.right-side-div {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

.container{
    height: 80vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display:flex;
}

#helpers-card{
    display:inline-block;
    min-height:138px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="card text-center bg-dark text-light" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title" id="item-name">Mana (<span id="total-mana-display" class="text-light-blue">0</span>)<span id="mana-increment-display"class="text-green" style="position: absolute; font-size: 1rem; display:none">+<span id="mana-increment-amount">1</span></span></h3>
          <p class="card-text" id="attributes-text">
  
          </p>
          <hr>
          <p class="card-text" id="req-text">
  
          </p>

          <button class="btn collect-btn" onclick="collectMana(player.mana.collectPower)">Collect</button>

        </div>

        
    </div>

    <div class="card text-center bg-dark text-light " id="helpers-card" style="width: 18rem;">
      
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title" id="item-name">Helpers</h3>
          <p class="card-text" id="attributes-text">
  
          </p>
          <hr>

          <div class="helper-container">

            <div class="buy-wisp-container" style="">
                <div class="left-side-div">
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-500" id="req-text">
                        Wisp (<span id="wisp-amount">0</span>)

                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores dolore atque est ratione aliquam hic?</span>
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="right-side-div" style="margin:0;float:right;width:50%">
                    
                    <button class="btn purchase-helper-btn font-weight-500" onclick="recruitHelper('wisp', 1)">Recruit (<span id="wisp-cost">5</span> mana)</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="buy-conjurer-container">
                <div class="left-side-div">
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-500" id="req-text">
                        Conjurer (<span id="conjurer-amount">0</span>)
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="right-side-div" style="margin:0;float:right;width:50%">
                    
                    <button class="btn purchase-helper-btn font-weight-500" onclick="recruitHelper('conjurer', 1)">Recruit (<span id="conjurer-cost">15</span> mana)</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="buy-excavator-container" style="">
                <div class="left-side-div">
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-500" id="req-text">
                        Excavator (<span id="excavator-amount">0</span>)
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="right-side-div" style="margin:0;float:right;width:50%">
                    
                    <button class="btn purchase-helper-btn font-weight-500" onclick="recruitHelper('excavator', 1)">Recruit (<span id="excavator-cost">10</span> mana)</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="buy-sciencewisp-container" style="">
                <div class="left-side-div">
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-500" id="req-text">
                        Science Wisp (<span id="excavator-amount">0</span>)
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="right-side-div" style="margin:0;float:right;width:50%">
                    
                    <button class="btn purchase-helper-btn font-weight-500" onclick="recruitHelper('sciencewisp', 1)">Recruit (<span id="sciencewisp-cost">10</span> mana)</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            

          </div> 
          
        </div>
        
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```